# how to MEAN hosting

Tags: angularjs, node.js, hosting, mean-stack

I'm having trouble understanding how the whole hosting for MEAN applications is done. If I want to use openshift for instance to host it.
I understand that it hosts the nodejs webserver and the mongodb but what about the angular app? I will need a apache server also?

Comment: angular run on client

Comment: but who is hosting the code? I have to put the code somewhere.

Comment: can be in same place as javascript files or css or images.

Comment: just install yeoman, and install [this](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack) generator, there is bunch of options ready made for that.

Comment: not the place in the filesystem, I mean in openshift? or somewhere else?

Comment: I guess I openshift (for instance) takes all that generated stuff then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75017/discussion-between-diogo-barroso-and-you).

Comment: sorry, read details in angular fullstack generator i posted above. I am casually checking some questions here.